# How to use Jenkins GitHub Organization Folder with github protected branches?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

It seems that some updates made in the last two weeks to Jenkins plugins or GitHub api introduce a very strange behaviour on GitHub.

Now we can prevent a PR from being merged if a specific Jenkins branch-job is not green but somehow it seems impossible to check if current PR is green.

If we do not select any branch in github repository configuration Jenkins build will not happen and the user would be able to merge the change.

If we check one of them Jenkins will build it and as a surprise we can see the job name that is matching the PR name. Wonderful, but somehow it seems that the generic check named "Jenkins" is still waiting for another status check, one that will never happen, preventing us from merging.

[image]
[image]

The last screenshot explains it the best: the named merge is green as expected but we also have another generic one "Jenkins" which is still "Waiting for status to be reported" but nothing is to be reported by Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

You must set Diplay Name for Github plugin, when it doesn't set, plugin fallbacks to build name.

I didn't find correct way to do this when we use Github Organization plugin with pipeline. And I implemented this by setting project properties from Jenkinsfile:

```
properties properties: [pipelineTriggers([]), [$class: 'GithubProjectProperty', displayName: 'Jenkins']]
```

And then set status manually:

```
step([$class: 'GitHubCommitStatusSetter', statusResultSource: [$class: 'ConditionalStatusResultSource', results: [[$class: 'BetterThanOrEqualBuildResult', message: 'Build success', result: 'SUCCESS', state: 'SUCCESS']]]])
```

This doesn't remove `Jenkins job PR-xxxx` status, but it adds `Jenkins` status wich you can use as required check